# Apache Flink number of taskmanagers in local mode

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on an Apache Flink (1.5.0) based streaming application.
As part of this I have launched Flink in local mode on my Windows machine.

In order to run my job with the degree of parallelism of 8, I need 8 Task managers providing one task slot each.

I added a task manager with following command:

```
/cygdrive/b/Binaries Flink/flink-1.5.0/bin/taskmanager.sh' start
```

The first few times, a task manager was added successfully with following message:

```
[INFO] 3 instance(s) of taskexecutor are already running on ... .
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host ... .
```

After 5 task managers were available I got the same message

```
[INFO] 5 instance(s) of taskexecutor are already running on ... .
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host ... .
```

The problem is that a sixth task manager is never created.
When I stop one task manager it goes down to 4, I can add one additional task manager but never more than 5 task managers.

Is there any limitation to the amount of task managers?
Did anyone experience a similar behaviour?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit of how many `TaskManager` you can start locally. The only limit is the available resources you have on your local machine.

If you are using the standalone mode in Flink `1.5.0`, then you can also set the number of slots per `TaskManager` to `7` by adding the following line to the `flink-conf.yaml`:

```
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 7
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I noticed today that several files named hs_err_pid1234 has been created in the bin-folder of Flink saying that there was unsufficient memory. Additionally, on a more powerful machine, adding as many TaskManagers as I wanted was no problem at all. Thank you also for the tip regarding the number of TaskSlots - didn't know about that.